# Parse.com's new app setup is not creating the config folder with the global json in it

Tags: json, parsing, setup-project, sendgrid

As per the Parse.com docs, a new app setup should create 3 folders, namely:
config, cloud and public.
For me, its creating only the cloud and public folders with their respective files, but no config folder with global.json in it.

I can't seem to be able to find this issue via google search.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create the folder config and inside of this folder one file global.config

with this code:

```
{
"applications": {
    "your app name": {
        "applicationId": "your app Id", 
        "masterKey": "your master key"
    }, 
    "_default": {
        "link": "your app name"
    }
}, 
"global": {
    "parseVersion": "1.3.3"
}
}
```

but if you don´t need use the master key if not necessary this file.